# PHP Fatal Error: Cannot open /dev/urandom: No such file or directory when calling session_start() with manually built PHP

Tags: linux, php, php-fpm, apache2

### Problem

I built PHP8.4 manually in Ubuntu 14.04 since the OS is out of support with no ppa package available. I tested for `phpinfo()` web page showed correct information while adding `session_start()` at the head of the script, a fatal error occurred:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Random\RandomException: Cannot open /dev/urandom: No such file or directory in /xxx.php
```

Then I run script `head /dev/urandom` in termial, I can get random output therefore the file is existed. When typing `ls -l /dev/urandom` the permission is `crw-rw-rw-` so it should be accessable by other users I think.

### Environment

- **Server hardware:** RK3288 armv7l cortex-A17 x4 cores with 2GB DDR3 RAM
- **Operation system:** Ubuntu 14.04 lts with kernel version 3.10.0
- **Web server:** Apache 2.4.7 with php-fpm fastcgi
- **PHP version:** 8.4.0-dev
- **Configure command when building php:**

```
'./configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/php/' '--enable-debug' \
  '--enable-fpm' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php/etc/' \ 
  '--enable-json' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-mbregex-backtrack' \
  '--disable-opcache' '--with-curl' '--with-freetype' \
  '--enable-gd' '--with-jpeg' '--with-gettext' '--with-kerberos' \
  '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-libxml' '--with-mysqli' \
  '--with-openssl' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--with-pdo-sqlite' \
  '--with-pear' '--with-mhash' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-xsl' \
  '--with-zlib' '--with-zip' '-with-bz2' '--with-iconv' \
  '--enable-pdo' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-mbstring' \
  '--disable-pcntl' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-soap' \
  '--enable-sockets' '--enable-xml' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-cli' \
  '--enable-intl' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-static' \
  '--enable-mysqlnd' 'OPENSSL_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/openssl/include' \
  'OPENSSL_LIBS=-L/usr/local/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto' \
  'JPEG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/' \
  'JPEG_LIBS=-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ -ljpeg' \
  'FREETYPE2_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/freetype2' \
  'FREETYPE2_LIBS=-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ -lfreetype' \
  'ICU_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/' \
  'ICU_LIBS=-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ -licui18n \
  -licuuc -licudata -licuio -licule -liculx -licutu' \
  'ONIG_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include' 'ONIG_LIBS=-L/usr/lib -lonig' \
  'LIBZIP_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include/' \
  'LIBZIP_LIBS=-L/usr/local/lib/ -lzip'
```

All errors output by configure were resolved before compiling PHP by manually compile all the missing dependencies.

I don't know where to start to check, please give some hints like which config file may not be properly set, which system info is worth checking, how to make it print more diagnose info about /dev/urandom etc. If any more information required for solving problem please comment and I'll improve my question description.

### Solusion

Thanks for @symcbean, he mentioned:

> Your PHP code be running chroot, or within an apparmor profile or in a systemd filesystem namespace.

With checking the conf file of php-fpm I found `chroot` was set. By unsetting the parameter, access php scripts with web browser showed `No input file specified`.

Then I checked my configuration of apache, I tried to add

```
ProxyFCGISetEnvIf "true" PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=..."
```

but my installed version of apache seems not recognize 'ProxyFCGISetEnvIf' with 'Invalid command' error throwed.

Finally I replaced

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/
```

with

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/path/to/webroot/$1
```

now every problems are solved.

**In a word**, if any `No such file or directory` error occurs in PHP, it's worth checking if you have set `chroot` for PHP.

Comment: It looks like you need to file a bug to the upstream, or to investigate it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I built PHP8.4 manually in Ubuntu 14.04 since the OS is out of support

This is a massive red flag. Keeping an out of support operating system running requires a LOT of skill and time. The *only* time when this is even remotely justifiable is to keep running mission critical software which cannot be upgraded. Changing the software stack on an out of support operating system is a recipe for disaster even for an expert and refutes the justification predicate.

> Then I run script head /dev/urandom in termial

This tells me you are not an expert.

The first place to look when diagnosing an error is in your log files. And not just your webserver logs.

/dev/urandom produces binary output which can mess up your terminal settings - it's safer to run `head /dev/urandom | cat -v`.

You did check the permissions - and since they are x666 the ownership doesn't matter (unless you have weird permissions on /dev). But the next step in debugging the issue would be to try to access the file directly from a PHP script. Your PHP code be running chroot, or within an apparmor profile or in a systemd filesystem namespace.

Upgrade the platform.